# Assign a std_ulogic_vector in one line without using the concatenate operator (&)

Tags: vhdl

I'm looking for a nice way of assigning std_(u)logic_vectors without manually adding zeros like in the code below. Example code:

```
signal test_32 : std_ulogic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal test_14 : std_ulogic_vector(13 downto 0);

test_32 <= "000000000000000000" & test_14; -- This works fine of course
```

Of course I can do:

```
test_32(13 downto 0)   <= test_14;
test_32(31 downto 14)  <= (others => '0');
```

I thought of something like this (to put everything in one line)
but this does not work:

```
test_32 <= (13 downto 0 => test_14, others => '0');
```

The code above works if the 14 lowest bits would also be constant:

```
test_32 <= (13 downto 0 => '1', others => '0');
```

Does anyone has a suggestion?

Comment: In both cases I get the same behaviour, can you check this [online simulation](https://www.edaplayground.com/x/2ktx)? Please give the problem that you are facing, not just `does not work`

Comment: With package numeric_std_unsigned (-2008) `test_32 <= resize(test_14, test_32'length);`. If you look at the function resize in that package it calls the resize from numeric_std with the value type converted to unsigned and returns the result type converted to std_logic_vector (`test_32 <= std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(test_14), test_32'length));`, which also works for earlier VHDL revisions).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VHDL: Zero-Extend a fixed signal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548345/vhdl-zero-extend-a-fixed-signal-value)

Comment: Thanks @user1155120, the resize function `test_32 <= resize(test_14, test_32'length);` works fine for this.
But what is if I try to merge more than one signal together to test_32 e.g.
`test_32 <= (23 downto 14 => test_10, 13 downto 0 => test_14,  others => '0');`
The error I get: `Cannot resolve slice name as type ieee.std_logic_1164.STD_ULOGIC.`

Comment: Your last comment  would need concatenation - `test_32 <= resize(test_10 & test_14, test_32'length);` Notice these avoid using aggregates with the restriction on the use of `others`. (Before you go on about 'holes in the middle' use SHIFT_LEFT and/or SHIFT_RIGHT with RESIZE on slices. For std_logic_vector mapped to unsigned '0' filled.) As long as the named choices and target is constrained your first aggregate should work in -2008 (IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates, para 7 e), may not be widely supported (overlooked, hard to implement). Show a [mcve].