# Assigning a vector of variable length to a static sized vector in VHDL

Tags: generics, aggregate, vhdl

I have a 32-bit output (rd_data) that is supposed to concatenate '0's with a w-bit signal (mux_out) but I'm not sure how to combine the two.

```
signal mux_out : std_logic_vector(w-1 downto 0);
signal rd_data : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal rd : std_logic;

with rd select

       rd_data <= (OTHERS => '0') when '0',
                 **32-BIT CONCATENATION OF ZEROES AND MUX_OUT** when '1';
```

How would i do this???? w will never be bigger than 32

Comment: Here's an example of where a [mcve] or information on your tool chain might help. -2008 has package numeric_std_unsigned and function RESIZE where your concatenation could be `RESIZE(mux_out, 32)` which left fills with zeros, treating std_logic_vector as an unsigned binary value, noting coverage of all values of `rd` in the selected signal assignment also requires an `others` choice (IEEE Std 1076-2008 10.5.4 Selected signal assignments, 10.9 Case statement). The equivalent concatenation in Synopsys package std_logic_arith might be `EXT(mux_out, 32)`.

Comment: Prior to -2008 IEEE package numeric_std can be used with type conversion (std_logic_vector and unsigned are closely related):  `std_logic_vector(resize(unsigned(mux_out, 32)))` for a concatenation expression.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VHDL: Zero-Extend a fixed signal value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548345/vhdl-zero-extend-a-fixed-signal-value)

Answer (score 0):

Without VHDL-2008:

```
   rd_data <= (OTHERS => '0') when '0',
             (rd_data'length-1 downto MUX_OUT'length => '0') &  MUX_OUT when '1',
             (others => 'X') when others ;  -- since rd is std_logic
```

Note that if MUX_OUT'length = rd_data'length, then "(rd_data'length-1 downto MUX_OUT'length => '0')" is still legal as it returns a NULL array (value = "").

With VHDL-2008:

```
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all; -- in context clause
. . . 
   rd_data <= (OTHERS => '0') when '0',
            resize(MUX_OUT, rd_data'length) when '1',
             (others => 'X') when others ;  -- since rd is std_logic
```